# Pods communication in kubernetes ingress egress

Tags: kubernetes

If I have two pods running on different namespaces, and there is netpol already setup and cannot be modified, how would I approach the POD to POD communication making the ingress and egress possible again without modifying the existing object?

Comment: The netpolicy that is already there probably does a general ingres / egress block.  If you add another policy that specifically allows the POD to POD you need then it will, in this case override the general policy.  See https://serverfault.com/questions/951958/does-order-of-network-policies-matter-in-kubernetes/952221

Comment: Did the suggest from Vorsprung help you?

Answer (score 1):

User [Vorsprung](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1153938/vorsprung) has good mentioned in the comment:

> The netpolicy that is already there probably does a general ingres / egress block. If you add another policy that specifically allows the POD to POD you need then it will, in this case override the general policy. See https://serverfault.com/questions/951958

Yes, you can add another network policy according to your needs and everything should work.  It doesn't matter in which order you apply your rules.

Look also [here](https://github.com/ahmetb/kubernetes-network-policy-recipes). You can find many [kubernetes network policies recipes](https://github.com/ahmetb/kubernetes-network-policy-recipes).

Comment: Thanks, I will check on that, appreciate yoru time to answer

Comment: Please [react on this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) if it was helpful.

Comment: However what if you cannot modify what is already in place, or if you cannot create new objects?